# How to read multiple ids from URL in cgi

Tags: arrays, perl, cgi

I'm passing thru a URL multiple values for id. and I'm trying to read all of those values and run a mysql query for each of the value.

The values came from a select all option on a different page.

This is my url

```
signout.cgi?id=98,100,50,3,2,5,6
```

How can I read the values from the url?

Comment: What are you need? Example of SQL query or example of parser?

Comment: @ya.ymer how to read the values from the url :/

Comment: What framework/middlework do you use for your Perl program getting the HTTP request? Whatever it is it certainly has a method to retrieve all HTTP content, including the `id` parameter, you will get a string that you can then split on `.` for your needs.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek using CGi, I know that I can get the values using ->param but I don't know how to loop thru them

Comment: Besides being a bad idea, did you look at `CGI.pm` manual (`perldoc CGI`) to stumble upon the `param` or `multi_param` methods? What is not clear about them? You do not loop, you get a string, you have to split it, see `perldoc -f split`. And then `for`, `foreach`, or `while` to loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one value. Extract it, and split the string at the commas.

```
use URI             qw( );
use URI::QueryParam qw( );

my $url = URI->new('signout.cgi?id=98,100,50,3,2,5,6', 'http');
my $id_param = $url->query_param('id');
my @ids = split /,/, $id_param;
```

In the comments, you seem to be saying you don't have a URL at all, but a CGI.pm object.

```
use CGI qw( );

my $cgi = CGI->new();
my $id_param = $cgi->param('id');
my @ids = split /,/, $id_param;
```